# How to avoid CORS error on testnet?

Tags: eosjs, testnet

When accessing an eos contract via eosjs, it works fine on a local net, but raises an error on testnet (jungle):

```
Access to fetch at 'https://jungle.eosn.io/v1/chain/get_abi' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

Any ideas?

Code is within:

https://github.com/lazaridiscom/dapp-platform/tree/master/eos

Answer (score 0):

CORS policy is set on server side typically. Can you try another API?

[monitor.jungletestnet.io/#apiendpoints](https://monitor.jungletestnet.io/#apiendpoints)

(Answered by https://eosio.stackexchange.com/users/1049/nat)